# How to arrange partials in parent view using bootstrap in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 4 partials and want to put these partials in the parent view. Currently, I am using a container to put all the partials together but I want to display the partials in the given order which I have shown in the code.

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           ABC
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

        </div>

       <div id="container">
          @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialABC", Model); }//Currently I am displaying all the partials here 
       // Want to display _PartialA here
       </div>                
   </div>
 </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            // Want to display _PartialB here
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           // Want to display _PartialC here
           // Want to display _PartialD here
        </div>
    </div>
```

_Partials

```
@model Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA

<div id="myA">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialA", Model.firsts); }
</div>
<div id="myB">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialB", Model.seconds);}
</div>
<div id="myC">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialC", Model.thirds);}
    </div>
<div id="myD">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialD", Model.fourths);}
</div>
```

Comment: You cant - your `_PartialABC` should contain the `<div class="col-md-5">` and `<div class="panel panel-default">` etc elements

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I can't place the partials in the given order.

Comment: Your question states that you want `_PartialB ` in the `<div class="panel-heading">` - so that element (and the other `<div>` elements) go in the `_PartialABC`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, how to place _partialA?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, can you please help me.

Comment: why you don't use partials separately in each div you want, for example put `@{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialA", Model.firsts); }` in division `<div id="container">` and so on.